# What's a way for producing stable, predictable and unique key for React list items?

Tags: reactjs

From React docs:

**Keys should be stable, predictable, and unique. Unstable keys (like those produced by Math.random()) will cause many component instances and DOM nodes to be unnecessarily recreated, which can cause performance degradation and lost state in child components.**

Why doesn't `Math.random()` produce stable, predictable and unique keys, and what's a way for producing them besides using `ids` generated by databases?

It's honestly very frustrating that react docs skips detailing such an important thing.

Comment: Because it depends on what data you are operating on, and how you produce the data and your state management. If the order of the array never changes, you can simply use the array index.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm trying to build a todolist, the order of the elements will change in an unpredictable order

Comment: I think the disclaimer about Math.random() being unstable applies to keys created in the render function, like this: `<Component key={Math.random() />`. If you create unique keys ahead of time and store them in the state, you could use Math.random() to produce keys. You could also use [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) for better guarantee of uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling to unterstand that. The docs are not very clear about it